# How to stop a mesh from passing past the mirror point and merge with the part added by the mirror

Tags: workflow, mirror

I am using a mirror to merge the mesh with its mirror created counterpart but it simply passes through the mirror and overlaps with it instead. Is there a way to automatically merge them in the centre like shown in the 2nd image or is the only way to apply the mirror and manually find the centre, cut it vertically and remove the excess

Here is an image of the mesh after applying the mirror modifier:

[image: 1]]

Here is an image of the manually merged mesh:

[image: 2]]

Comment: Just check in the "Clipping" on the Mirror Modifier. If you already have overlapping verts, first move the whole mesh away from the mirror axis, then enable the clipping and move back to the original position.

Comment: I've tried that but when I enable "Clipping" and extrude them towards the mirror axis it warps the mesh by pushing the vertices upwards. Example: https://i.gyazo.com/2d81d425c10a57362c405c39fe73625c.png

Comment: constrain the vertices on the "x" axis by typing the "x" key while moving them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you apply the mirror modifier as seen in the picture below, it will clip the mesh and auto merge it

[image]

[image]

It's specifically about these 2 values.

Comment: Thanks that worked, now I can use the mirror modifier without having to worry if cleaning up the mess created by using it will take more time than just doing it manually without using it.